# ASP.NET Core Linux не загружаются файлы

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net

Всем привет. Только разобрался с БД PostgreSQL и снова появляется проблема. Дело в том, что какого бы размера файл я не пытался бы загрузить на Linux, загрузка проходит неуспешно, выдает код 500. Я даже пробовал загружать картинки по 32 Кб, все равно нет толку. Уменьшил ограничение размера загружаемых файлов в nginx.conf. Повысил до 100Мб, но толку нет. В чем может быть проблема? Может в настройках nginx вообще отключена загрузка файлов? Как я могу это проверить?

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}
http {
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        # server_tokens off;
        #proxy_set_boty on;
        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        ##
        # Gzip Settings
 ##
        gzip on;
        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Честно говоря, практически не работал на Linux. До данного момента столкнулся с ним всего один раз. Поэтому могу ошибиться в вопросе. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А исключение-то вы посмотрели какое возникает?

Comment: Почему подозрение пало на nginx? Может проблема в контроллере ASP.NET? Приведите больше информации.